# Blank fragment pattern in Android Studio 2.1.1

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Do we really need these lines?

```
public MyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
...

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
```

If android complies to java and we don't have any constructor with parameters an empty one will be generated automatically. Anyway we should use factory method `newInstance()`. Is it just as a precaution?

Why do we bother about listener? As far as I understand in this case fragment may hold the host activity from GC reaping. On configuration change `onAttach()` will re-new reference and on permanent detachment the fragment it will be destroyed with mListener.